# How to get all data from a server variable in PHP?

Tags: php

How would I get all the data from fields that have been posted or requested using get in PHP?

e.g

```
echo $_GET[*];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var_dump ($_GET);
```

or

```
print_r ($_GET);
```

or

```
echo (json_encode ($_GET));
```

or

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
{
    echo ($key . ', ' . $val);
}
```

or any number of other methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use print_r:

```
<?php
...
print_r($_GET)
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the values of an array or an object, you can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). You'll want to use it inside `<pre>` tags to get all the indentation and new lines.

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_GET); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extract($_GET);
```

fun with extract!